# Change background image with styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to change the backgroundImage dynamiclly, when i try it follow as, it did not work,but when i open the devtools in chrome, can show that background

```
<RecommendWrapper>
     <RecommendItem imgUrl="../../static/banner.png" >
     </RecommendItem>  
</RecommendWrapper>

export const RecommendItem = styled.div`
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: contain;
    background: url(${(props)=>props.imgUrl});  
`;
```

[image]

if i use like this,it can work,but can't change image dynamic.

```
import banner from "../../statics/banner.png"
export const RecommendItem = styled.div`
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: contain;
    background:url(${banner}); 
`;
```

and if i use a network image(url likes "https://syean.cn/img/avatar.jpg") ,it also can work

Comment: Where are you assigning it dynamically?

Comment: actually，the real code is like this`{
               
                this.props.recommendList.map((item)=>(
                    <RecommendItem key={item.get("id")} imgUrl={item.get("imgUrl")} >
                    ddd
                    </RecommendItem>
                ))
            }`

Comment: Can you create stackblitz of it?

Comment: ok,I create on the codesandbox ,url is https://codesandbox.io/s/wv2xvkxo8,the file is "src/pages/home/components/recommends.js",relative style file is "src/pages/home/style.js" ,line 94,thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your file in public folder and try this command:

```
<RecommendItem imgUrl={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/banner.png'} >
```

Comment: @syean Because of your browser has access to **public** folder from outside.

Comment: If you write src="abc.png" it means that your browser will make get request to `http://localhost:3000/abc.png` and it can't look inside **src** folder

Comment: This is wrong. Look at @naved-khan answer below.

Answer (score 61):

React, Gatsby and Next.js all generally use Webpack, which compiles your site before deployment. They will minify imagery and change each image's path.

In order to get images to load properly, you have to reference them dynamically as an import. This way, the variable URL will still work after Webpack does its thing.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import img from './img/bg.gif';
    
const Content = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: url(${img});
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
`;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for advice  i will update it soon with example

Comment: This should be the most recent answer. `url(${img})` works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

import your image and try this command

```
import YourImage from "../filepath"

    export const RecommendItem = styled.div`
    background: url(${YourImage?.src});  
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
// used as 
<Heading image={require('./images/headerBackground.jpg')} />

// a styled component
const Container = styled.div`` 
// the class made as
class Heading extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container image={this.props.backgroundimage}>
          <Logo />
          <Navigation />
          <HeadingBox />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
export default Heading;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create next.config.js in project's root dir and add this code:

```
const webpack = (config, options) => {

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      // name: '[path][name].[ext]',

      name() {
        // `resourcePath` - `/absolute/path/to/file.js`
        // `resourceQuery` - `?foo=bar`

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
          return '[path][name].[ext]';
        }

        return '[contenthash].[ext]';
      },
      publicPath: `/_next/static/images`,
      outputPath: 'static/images',
      limit: 1000,
    },
  });

  return config
}

module.exports = { webpack }
```

Do not forget install file-loader if not installed yet.

```
yarn add -D file-loader
```

Then in your component you may do like this:

```
const imgUrl = require("../../static/banner.png").default;

<RecommendItem imgUrl={imgUrl} >
```

Will be used abs url from bandles.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the questioner is using Next.JS. Please try to ask questions to get information about their setup if it's not clear before posting an answer that related to a specific environment like Next.JS.

Comment: Yeah, in the question, its clear that this is a reactjs and styled components  Question,based on the tags below the question.Always check the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the function in the background-image value return a string, url(your_image_link).

```
<RecommendWrapper>
     <RecommendItem imgUrl="img_link" >
     </RecommendItem>  
</RecommendWrapper>

export const RecommendItem = styled.div`
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: contain;
    background: ${(props) => `url(${props.imgUrl})`};
```