# Styled components background image not showing

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

```
    <MentionLayout
      iconSender={
        mention.sender.logo ? (
          <UserIcon imageUrl={mention.sender.logo} />
        ) : (
          <PersonOutlinedSmall />
        )
      }
      unreadMessagesCount={mention.messages}
    >
      ...
    </MentionLayout>
```

```
 const UserIcon = styled.div<{ imageUrl: string }>`
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background-image: ${({ imageUrl }) => `url(${imageUrl})`};
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`
```

For some reason, the `UserIcon` does not show the picture content (nor does the fallback icon appear)

It works only if I put the actual URL of the image into  `background-image` property but I can't do that since I have dynamic logos

Comment: looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920405/change-background-image-with-styled-component  might help you to fix the problem